# UINavigationController not updating size with auto layout iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, ios8, autolayout

I'm trying to update my app to be compatible with iOS8 I found some bugs in the App with the Autolayouts of the `UINavigationController` when I rotate the device to landscape mode the root view updates but the subviews doesn't update even the sub-views of the `Scrollview`.

The App is for iPhone and iPad so I use two separate storyboards and I use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.shouldAdjustChildViewHeightForStatusBar = NO;
  [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
  UIStoryboard *storyboard;
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
  }

  self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeController"];
}
```

The image

[image]

Below is the view as you see is in landscape mode an there is a big white space because the Scrollview did not update or something

I use to update the subview but the scroll did not work.

```
 -(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
```

Comment: What is `topViewController`? In UINavigationController, this is a readonly property, so it cannot be assigned to.

Comment: my topViewController is part of the ECSlidingViewController framework for the menu i'm using for this App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear from your question but it looks like you are subclassing `ECSlidingViewController`.

[If you look at the source for ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/blob/master/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController.m#L134), it only lays out the topViewController in its `viewDidLoad`.

**Solution 1:**

You want the topViewController to be set before `viewDidLoad` is called, and they do it in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [super awakeFromNib];

  UIStoryboard *storyboard;
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
  } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
  }    
  self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeController"];    
}
```

**Solution 2**

They seem to have a nice convenience method to initialize a sliding view controller. Wherever you are creating your ECSlidingViewController, you could rather do:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
}    
UIViewController *topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeController"];
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = [ECSlidingViewController slidingWithTopViewController:topViewController];
// ...
```

Comment: thank you this works fine it seems i was using a older version of the ECSlindingViewController with the proyect also the `UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
}`this part of code is unnecessary because is defined in the Deployment info tab of the project,that will be useful if you don't wanna use the Size Clases with Storyboards